# Асинхронное чтение из сокета (C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d, async-await, асинхронность

Необходимо асинхронно читать данные из сокета (`NetworkStream`) и выполнять действия в зависимости от считанных данных. В бескрайних просторах интернета встречается несколько парадигм, две из которых EAP (event-based asynchronous programming) и TAP (task-based asynchronous programming).

Второй вариант хорошо подходит для моей задачи, но, увы, ключевые слова `async` и `await` введены с 5-й версии C#, которую Unity (на которой у меня проект) не поддерживает. По EAP не нашёл понятных примеров, поэтому слабо представляю, как им пользоваться.

Подскажите, как реализовать асинхронное чтение из сокета?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NetworkStream` не поддерживает EAP. Кроме TAP он поддерживает [APM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) методами [`BeginRead()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`EndRead()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.endread(v=vs.110).aspx). APM -- это asynchronous programming model, самая первая реализация асинхронного программирования в .NET.

Процесс чтение данных при этом будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
AsyncCallback callback = 
    ar =>
    { 
        int bytesRead = myNetworkStream.EndRead(ar);

        // обрабатываем полученные данные

        // при необходимости снова читаем данные
        networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, null);
    };

// первоначальный вызов,
// networkStream как вариант можно передавать в качестве последнего параметра,
// а затем получать его из IAsyncResult.AsyncState
networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, null);
```

Comment: То есть при первоначальном вызове поток управления не "стопорится" и продолжает работать?

Comment: @KamoSpertsian да.

Comment: понял, спасибо, попробую реализовать.

Comment: @KamoSpertsian не за что! Возникнут проблемы -- задавайте новые вопросы.